# PySpark : Performance optimzation during create_map for categorizing the page visit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on optimizing the below operation whose exection time is relatively high on the actual dataset(large datset).I tried below on two of the pyspark dataset 1 & 2 to arrive at the "page_category" column of dataset-2

pyspark dataset-1 :

```
page_click | page_category
---------------------------
facebook | Social_network
insta    | Social_nework
coursera | educational
```

Another dataset on which i am applying the create_map operation looks like :

```
pyspark dataset-2 :

id | page_click
---------------
1  | facebook
2  |Coursera
```

I am creating the dictionary of the dataset-1 and applying the

`page_map = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*dict_dataset_1.items()])`
`dataset_2.withColumn('page_category', page_map[dataset_2['page_click']])`

and then performing  with_column on 'page_click' column of dataset-2 to arrive at the another column called 'page_category'

```
final dataset : 

id | page_click | Page_category
-------------------------------
1  | facebook   |social_network
2  |Coursera    |educational
```

But this operation is taking too much time to complete, more than 4-5 minutes. Is there another way to speed up the operation ?

Thank you

Comment: how about a simple join?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a simple broadcast join

```
df2.join(broadcast(df1),df2.page_click==df1.page_click,'left').\
    select(df2.id, df2.page_click, df1.page_category).show()

+---+----------+--------------+
| id|page_click| page_category|
+---+----------+--------------+
|  1|  facebook|Social_network|
|  2|  coursera|   educational|
+---+----------+--------------+
```